# r leaflet: how to obtain lat/long where marker has been dragged to?

Tags: r, leaflet

in R's version of leaflet, How can I obtain the lat longs of where markers have been dragged to?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('map'),
    textOutput('dragEndLocation')
)

server = function(input, output, session){
    output$map = leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers(lat = 1,lng = 2, options = markerOptions(draggable = TRUE)

    output$dragEndLocation = renderText({
        ???
    })
}
```

I see in javascript leaflet, there is an event called `dragEnd` that you can listen for, but it is not implemented in R leaflet. ([leaflet.js - Set marker on click, update position on drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575722/leaflet-js-set-marker-on-click-update-position-on-drag))

This person ([How to update coordinates after dragging a marker in leaflet shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549325/how-to-update-coordinates-after-dragging-a-marker-in-leaflet-shiny)) made a hack-y workaround by listening for `input$map_marker_mouseout` and then checking if the lat long has changed, but it is not ideal. When you drag a marker very quickly, mouseout will register several times. It is not a problem for this minimal working example, but for my actual application which wants to a slower script after drag end, it makes this workaround very buggy and slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but I came looking for the same and figured it out:

```
observe({
    print(input$map_marker_dragend)
})
```

In other words - the event you were looking for was **dragend**